# How to use a JComboBox with null value and using generic types?

Tags: java, generics, null, jcombobox, classcastexception

I use a `JComboBox` with generics (Java 7) and is very useful as I don't need to cast all the time and also I use custom render to display the objects correctly.

My problem comes when I add a null value as it throw a `java.lang.ClassCastException`. My `ListCellRenderer` is Ok, it can handle `null` values but this exception happen before it can render it.

What I had found is that `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI` do this:

```
if (value == null) {
      value = " ";
} else if (value instanceof String && "".equals(value)) {
      value = " ";
}
Component component = renderer.getListCellRendererComponent(listBox, value, -1, false, false);
```

So it convert the `null` into a white space `String` and therefore the class cast exception.

The only thing I can think is make that my rederer accept Object type and check there the class of the value and if it is a `" "` suppose that is like `null` (witch I don't see it to be very correct).

This line throw the exception `Component component = renderer.getListCellRendererComponent(listBox, value, -1, false, false);` as value is a String and the rendered only accept MyClass objects.

What can be done? Is it a way to avoid this conversion?

---

Here is a code like the one I used:

```
JComboBox plantillaMarcoB = new JComboBox<MyClass>();
plantillaMarcoB.setRenderer(new Visualizador);
DefaultComboBoxModel<MyClass> modeloA = new DefaultComboBoxModel<MyClass>();
modeloB.addElement(null);
modeloB.addElement(new MyClass());
this.plantillaMarcoB.setModel(modeloB);
```

And this is the Visualizador class:

```
package es.phoneixs;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;

import es.phoneixs.MyClass;


public class Visualizador extends JLabel implements
        ListCellRenderer<MyClass> {

    public Visualizador() {

        setOpaque(true);
        setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);

    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList<? extends MyClass> list,
            MyClass value, int index, boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {

        this.setFont(list.getFont());

        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
            setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            setBackground(list.getBackground());
            setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }

        if (value == null) {

            this.setText("No usar la plantilla");

        } else {

            this.setText(String.format("%1$s - %2$s - %3$s",  value.getDescripcionCas(), value.getCodigo(), value.getTurno()));

        }

        return this;

    }

}
```

This is the exception throw:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to es.phoneixs.MyClass
    at es.phoneixs.Visualizador.getListCellRendererComponent(Visualizador.java:1)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.getBaseline(BasicComboBoxUI.java:979)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI.getBaseline(MetalComboBoxUI.java:149)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getBaseline(JComponent.java:2561)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$ComponentSpring.getBaseline(GroupLayout.java:3075)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$BaselineGroup.calculateBaselineAndResizeBehavior(GroupLayout.java:2732)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$BaselineGroup.calculateSize(GroupLayout.java:2708)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1602)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1346)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.getSpringSize(GroupLayout.java:1638)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculateSize(GroupLayout.java:1627)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1602)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1346)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.getSpringSize(GroupLayout.java:1638)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculateSize(GroupLayout.java:1622)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1602)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1346)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.getSpringSize(GroupLayout.java:1638)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculateSize(GroupLayout.java:1622)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.calculatePreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1602)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Spring.getPreferredSize(GroupLayout.java:1346)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$SequentialGroup.setValidSize(GroupLayout.java:2017)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$Group.setSize(GroupLayout.java:1587)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.calculateAutopadding(GroupLayout.java:1079)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.layoutContainer(GroupLayout.java:920)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1503)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1492)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1688)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1697)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1623)
    at java.awt.CardLayout.show(CardLayout.java:547)
```

Comment: @kocko what is "NPE"?

Comment: It isn't a NPE, it is a ClassCastException

Comment: Sorry, I am still sleepy :)

Comment: The error clear occurs within getListCellRendererComponent in the Visualizador class...

Comment: @Tom sorry, I have made also many changes at the same time of yours.

Comment: `Vizualizador.java:1` is bogus. We need the *actual* line of code where the CCE is thrown. BTW by inspecting the source code of the method I don't actually see any line which could throw it.

Comment: I have edited the question to remark the line that throw the exception

Comment: I think that the question is a little more clear now. Please if it is Ok don't down vote it and if no, tell me what is the problem. And thank you all to try to help me.

Comment: @Tom I used your stacktrace, thank you and sorry for the overwrite.

Comment: @PhoneixS Ok. Always remember to use "code" formatting instead of "block quote" for stacktraces. It is much more readable that way.

Comment: @Tom, Yes I thought that was better to use quote but you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it is a bug in the implementation of jvm. You can see the report in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7195179 unfortunately it seems to be fixed for Java 8.

The only work around I found is to change Visualizador to also accept the string.

```
package es.phoneixs;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;

import es.phoneixs.MyClass;


public class Visualizador extends JLabel implements
        ListCellRenderer<Object> {

    public Visualizador() {

        setOpaque(true);
        setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);

    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList<? extends Object> list,
            Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {

        this.setFont(list.getFont());

        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
            setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            setBackground(list.getBackground());
            setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }

        if (value == null || (value instanceof String && value.equals(" "))) {

            this.setText("No usar la plantilla");

        } else if (value instanceof MyClass) {

            this.setText(String.format("%1$s - %2$s - %3$s",  value.getDescripcionCas(), value.getCodigo(), value.getTurno()));

        } else {
            this.setText(value.toString());
        }

        return this;

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I just arrived to the same conclusion by inspecting the source code. They generified the class without making the code using it typesafe. The CCE is thrown at the method call site, where an implicit downcast into your class happens. The cast is not visible in source code, therefore the "line 1" presented in the stack trace.